# Unreadable result when clicking ListView

Tags: android, listview, toast

I am displaying a list of peoples names in a ListView.
When I click on a name I have it set up to display a Toast message showing the name of the person clicked.

However the toast is displaying unreadable data and I can't figure out how to make it just display the name.

Below is the toast message:

"**com.example.friends.Person@50db3a clicked!**"

I wanna display something like

**"Joe bloggs clicked!".**

The list gets its data from an arraylist containing Person objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `toString()` method in Person class and return the person's name or whatever you want to appear. For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: You should set this answer as the right one. This is how SO works.

Comment: @FlávioFaria Remember that a poster cannot accept an answer for 15 minutes after they ask. (*At the time you posted that, it had been around 6 minutes.*)

Comment: @Eric sorry, I didn't know that.